# Why does "!= 'NULL'" give the same result as "is not NULL"

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table

```
EID  Name     changed_id 
1    Ashish   (NULL)
2    Sudhir    (NULL)
3    AKASH     123456
```

**QUERY**

```
SELECT EID,Name,
IF(changed_id !='NULL','Y','N') AS FLAG
FROM EMPLOYEE
```

**OUTPUT**

```
EID  Name     FLAG
1    Ashish    N
2    Sudhir    N
3    AKASH     Y
```

I know this is not the way how I should deal with NULL values. I should use `IF(changed_id is not NULL,'Y','N')` instead of `IF(changed_id !='NULL','Y','N')`. They both give the correct result. Can any one give any explanation why this is the case?

Comment: Please don't __YELL IN CAPS__. It's very hard to concentrate on your question and makes it difficult to get to the point.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL mystery: Null value is not different from non-null string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404766/mysql-mystery-null-value-is-not-different-from-non-null-string)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT 
    EID,
    Name,
    (
        CASE 
            WHEN NOT changed_id IS NULL OR NOT changed_id = 'NULL' 
            THEN 'Y' 
            ELSE 'N' 
        END 
    )AS FLAG
FROM 
    EMPLOYEE
```

**Update**

To answer the comment. We need to check for both `IS NULL` and = `'NULL'`. Because of the reason that `NULL!='NULL'`. `NULL` will never be equals the string value of `'NULL'`.

I would suggest that the OP checks where actuality (s)he insert or update so that the value of the column becomes the string `'NULL'` and make sure that it is `NULL`. Then the OP doesn't need to check for both cases.

**Update #2:**

> For people new to the subject, a good way to remember what null means
>   is to remember that in terms of information, "lack of a value" is not
>   the same thing as "a value of zero"; similarly, "lack of an answer" is
>   not the same thing as "an answer of no". For example, consider the
>   question "How many books does Juan own?" The answer may be "zero" (we
>   know that he owns none) or "null" (we do not know how many he owns, or
>   doesn't own). In a database table, the column reporting this answer
>   would start out with a value of null, and it would not be updated with
>   "zero" until we have ascertained that Juan owns no books.

Reference:

- [Null (SQL)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_(SQL))

Comment: Thanks For reply and suggestion.In My case I am focusing on 'NULL' and NULL differnce  in mysql as it giving me correct result even it is the wrong logic IF(changed_id !='NULL','Y','N').

Comment: @ASHISH.S : I updated the answer. Do you mean like this?

Comment: This does not answer the question ("why this is the case?").

Comment: @RandomSeed : I updated the answer. Happy with the explanation or do you want me to expand more?

Comment: Sorry if I sounded a bit harsh, I am having connection issues, so I couldn't reedit my comment in time. That's exactly what was bothering me: comparing `NULL` with `"NULL"` smells really bad. You have my +1.

Comment: @RandomSeed : No problem. I agree. That was why I suggested him to update the data to `NULL` not `'NULL'` and thank you for the feedback. My original answer did not answer the OPs question directly.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to explain my point of view about `NULL` but a warn you that it is an abstract thought.

`NULL` is nothing.

If you ask 5 is greater than `NULL` the result is no. If you ask 5 is lesser than `NULL` the answer is still no, because ´NULL´ is nothing and when you compare anything with `NULL` the answer always is No.

So, when you ask, if a variable is equals to `NULL`, the result is `NULL` because nothing can be equals to `NULL`.

Comment: @ASHISH.S And above all, the value `NULL` is never equal to the string `'NULL'` (it is *never* equal to *any* string for that matter).